# Using Byobu in multiple servers with the same configuration

Tags: byobu

This is from the creator of Byobu (answering some other question):

> I started writing Byobu back in December of 2008, as I met up with a
>   bunch of Screen and Ubuntu Server users at the Googleplex and found
>   that all of us maintained our own bunch of neat/fun/useful hacks in
>   our ~/.screenrc configurations. **And we had to manually move those
>   around between the dozens or hundreds of servers we used**. We started
>   trading tips and tricks, and I began to collect those into the
>   original GPLv3 project called "screen-profiles". About 6 months later,
>   a whole community had developed around "screen-profiles" and the
>   project became much more than just screen hacks -- we had
>   configuration utilities, live status plugins, and keybindings.

I usually use tmux, and also find annoying that each server I log into has its own tmux configuration (specially key bindings!). How can I make byobu use the same configuration everywhere?

Not sure if  this is relevant, but I usually use nested tmuxes (my machine/server).

Answer (score 0):

This problem isn't really specific to `byobu` or `tmux`. As long as you have personal preferences for how things should work, you'll have to manage your own set of dotfiles.

There are a lot of strategies people use to do that. Here are a few related links/questions:

http://vcs-home.branchable.com/

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/1875/tips-for-putting-under-source-control

There are lots more if you search for "home directory version control" or "dotfile version control".

Comment: Sure, I realize that. But the sentence seems to imply byobu has an alternative/easier solution. Or did I misunderstand?

Comment: Well, it sounds like they simply created a large collection of customizations and put it into a `screen-profiles` package. But you'd still need to install this `screen-profiles` package via the system package manager, which isn't terribly easier than just pulling your own dotfiles in an automated way.